# RecycleView displaying only the first item

Tags: android

Here is the problem: I create the simplest RecyclerView in the world, but it displays only the first item. I cannot understand why. Thanks for any help.

**item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv_detail"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bcit.moonlady.testrecycler.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/tv_hello"/>

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/rv_details"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_hello"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.bcit.moonlady.testrecycler;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String[] data = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};

    RecyclerView mRecView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_details);
        mRecView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecView.setLayoutManager(new    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        mRecView.setAdapter(new DetailAdapter());
   }

   private class DetailView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTextView;

        public DetailView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail);
        }

        public void bindView(String string) {
            mTextView.setText(string);
        }
   }

   private class DetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailView> {
       @Override
       public DetailView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)          {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
            return new DetailView(v);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(DetailView holder, int position) {
           String string = data[position];
           holder.bindView(string);
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return data.length;
       }
   } 
}
```

Comment: `mRecView.setLayoutManager(new    LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));` why are you passing application context to layout manager?

Comment: I think your recycleview layout not filled full for 3 items from top to bottom

Comment: http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example please refer this link. It might help you

Comment: I could use 'this' instead of 'getApplicationContext()', it's true;

Comment: That example from javatechig.com is good; thanks!

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You need to change your **item_layout** height as **wrap_content**
if your are using [Android Support Library v 23.2.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive.html#rev23-2-0) and above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv_detail"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Worked for me too. Using Support library 23.4.0

Comment: thanks for guidance I making the same mistake which moonlady16 did.

Comment: Maybe the OP should mark this as the accepted answer? (FWIW, it worked for me too!  Thanks a bunch!  I knew it was something like this, but I'm in the middle of an Android Development course and sending an e-mail to get an answer would have taken, well, longer than I wanted to wait.) ;)

Comment: @ramji Thank you! Was chasing that bug for a while.

Comment: Complementing @Ramji's response, if the item inserted in the RecycleView is parent-sized, the RecycleView algorithm will never insert the other elements, because RecycleView only adds new elements if the user scrolls up.
The RecycleView logic only adds elements to the screen if there is a hypothesis of the element being displayed in the ui

Comment: I am using AndroidX and this answer is still applicable.

Comment: I'm amazed, but this fixed the issue.  Thanks!  Is anyone able to explain the reason behind this?  I always like to know more of the "why" than the "how".  It helps with future issues.  :)

Answer (score 18):

I too made this common mistake. Just change your parent LinearLayout - height should be "wrap_content"

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
..... >
..
..
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem, when RecyclerView was wrapped in ScrollView. You should use NestedScrollView instead.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

          <!-- other content -->

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/my_recycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

 </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 5):

Set the height to wrap_content of the RelativeLayout in the item_layout.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv_detail"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

it may help

```
customAdapter = new CustomRecycleradapter(arrItems);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mParentActivity));
recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

ArrayList<ListofItems> mSource;
// adapter class
public CustomRecycleradapter(ArrayList<ListofItems> source) {
    this.mSource = source;

}
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new CustomHolder(view);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof CustomHolder) {
        ((CustomHolder) holder).customerName.setText(mSource.get(position).getCustomerNumber());

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mSource.size();
}

public void addItem(ArrayList<ListofItems> itemLists) {
    mSource.addAll(itemLists);

    notifyItemInserted(mSource.size() - 1);
}
public class CustomHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.customer_name)
    TextView customerName;
    @Bind(R.id.time_stamp)
    TextView timeStamp;
    @Bind(R.id.amount)
    TextView amount;

    public CustomHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a bit to make it running, but I'm glad I made it; I am now aware of ButterKnife. Thanks!...

Answer (score 1):

**Activity:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerView mRecycler;
String[] data = {"test1", "test2", "test3"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_details);
    DetailAdapter adapter = new DetailAdapter();
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
    mRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private class DetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DetailAdapter.DetailView> {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DetailView holder, int position) {
        String string = data[position];
        holder.bindView(string);
    }

    @Override
    public DetailView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        return new DetailView(v);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    class DetailView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTextView;

        public DetailView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail);
        }

    public void bindView(String string) {
        mTextView.setText(string);
    }
}

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv_details"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**item_layout.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv_detail"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example

Comment: @moonlady16 glad to help you, if it helped you pls upvote and mark as right answer bec it may help others too.

Answer (score 0):

First up, u should put your Recyclerview.veiwholder class inside the adapter to ensure youre getting the same instance.

```
//replaces contents of a view, invoked by the layout manager 
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) { 
// get the message to display from the array at the specified position 
// replace contents of the view with the new element
holder.mytextview.setText(recieveHistory.get(position)); 
}
```

Comment: Basically you're not allowing the recyclerView to recycle its views since youre statically assigning the ID of the TextView and then just setting a string to it.